# How to avoid if statement? for the compiler cannot optimize it to simd

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, if-statement, compiler-construction, simd

In vs2012 the compiler can automatically optimize the for loop into SIMD assembly statement.
But when a if statment is in the for loop, the compiler cannot optimize it,
just like:

```
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
{
    if(a[i]<1)
    {
        a[i]=0;
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to replace the if statments and let the compiler able to automatically optimize
it into simd code?

Comment: The compiler is an idiot. That's often the case when you're hoping for auto-vectorization. Try using intrinsics.

Comment: @harold, _all_ software programs are idiots since they do only what they're told to do and no more. I suspect you meant the compiler writers were idiots, certainly a possibility :-) But don't discount the difficulty of getting optimisation right, it's a notoriously difficult endeavour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could *try* trickery like:

```
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
    a[i] = a[i] * (a[i] >= 1);
```

but you should realise a few things.

First, it may end up *still* not being able to use SIMD. That'll depend on the compiler and how clever it may be.

Secondly, it *may* end up being slower, especially since you're performing a calculation on, and touching, every element in the array. This won't be too bad for the sample but, if your calculation is more complex, that can cause trouble.

Thirdly, if that *is* your real code, SIMD isn't really going to help that much for a simple calculation and minimal loop count (10,000 isn't really that much).

Comment: I tried, the compiler prompt that there have a if statement in the for loop so it can not be vectorization.Maybe this is an unavoidable problem to auto SIMD. My for loop is 4 layer big loop,so if it can be compiled to SIMD the speed could be improved,not so much since the calculation is so simple,may be a few times

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
{
     a[i] = a[i]<1 ? 0: a[i];
}
```

Comment: That's still an `if` statement.